# Hibernate connection pool provider for Cloud SQL

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Hibernate in combination with GAE and Cloud SQL.

Everything works fine, but when an instance is waken up, sometimes it takes a long time to connect to the database (up to 15s)

In the log I see that the most time it is Hibernate establishing a connection:

```
   I 17:46:35.936 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
   W 17:46:36.209 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
   I 17:46:36.243 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 0
   I 17:46:36.244 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
   I 17:46:36.244 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver] at URL [jdbc:google:mysql://database?user=someUser]
   I 17:46:36.245 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure: HHH000046: Connection properties: {}
   I 17:46:45.356 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Here is the code producing this:

```
properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:google:mysql://" + SQL_INSTANCE + "/" + DATABASE + "?user=someUser");

// disable schema check
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", ""); // disable
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);            

// single session per request/thread
properties.put("hibernate.connection.pool_size", 0);
properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");

Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml");
cfg.addProperties(properties);

sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry());
```

Following method provides the session

```
public Session getSession() {

        Session session;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        catch (org.hibernate.HibernateException he) {
            log.info("Opening new hibernate session.");
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }

        return session;
    }
```

I'm setting the connection pool size to 0 (as recommended), but apparently Hibernates build in connection pool manager is used.

My question is, which connection pool manager should be used in this setup, and what else can be done to speed up connection time.

What are the best practises for this kind of setup, as I can not find anything but some trivial examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you using [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), which is [probably the fastest open-source CP](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling/).

I have a [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/vladmihalcea.wordpress.com/blob/master/hibernate-facts/src/test/resources/spring/applicationContext-local-tx-test.xml) project you could clone and check my configuration for Hibernate local transaction configuration. Although the example uses DBCP you only need to replace the DataSource configuration with the [HikariDataSource one](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool/blob/master/flexy-hikaricp/src/test/resources/spring/applicationContext-test.xml).

If you are using only Hibernate API and don;t want to rely on SPring, then after you create your HikariDataSource object, you need to send it to Hibernate configuration:

```
@Override
protected SessionFactory newSessionFactory() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    ...
    //data source settings
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.datasource", hikariDataSource);
    return new Configuration()
    .addProperties(properties)
    .addAnnotatedClass(SecurityId.class)
    .buildSessionFactory(
            new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(properties)
    .build()
);
```

Comment: Will give it a shot and compare start up times ... might do the trick.

Comment: Sadly I couldn't get it to work with GAE. It works on localhost but it doesn't in production. So I have using this open source connection pool provider: https://hibernate-gae.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hibernate-gae-connection-pool/src/fi/foyt/hibernate/gae/connection/GAEConnectionProvider.java

Comment: It looks like a basic connection pooling implementation but it may use some specific GAE connection retrieval options that other external pools may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

An [ON_DEMAND](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta3/instances#settings.activationPolicy) SQL instance will shutdown after an idle period. When the instance is shut down any new connections must wait for the instance to start up before the connection will be completed.

It is possible that this is the delay you are experiencing. You can try changing the activation policy to ALWAYS and see if this reduces the connection overhead. If you do this you should also change the billing plan to "Package" as it will be cheaper considering your instance will be running continuously.

This is covered in the [Cloud SQL FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sometimes_slow).

Comment: As far as I can see it in the logs .. the main portion of the time is used for establishing a connection. This happens on every warm up request when a new instance is starting. This is not a mission critical app, so having instances up and running is overkill. I suspect (but can not prove) that the internal hybernate connection pool manager is causing the delay (as it is not a production scale implementation, nor it is meant to be used in GAE style). I will try and change the settings, will see what happens.